# Photographic suggestions in White Mountain Forest & Acadia Park

Tags: travel, landscape

I am going to White Mountain Forest (New Hampshire) and Acadia Park (Maine) in August. Any photographic related suggestions on those 2 beautiful parks?

Comment: There is some disagreement about whether or not this type of question should be on-topic here. See the discussion here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Equipment tips, location tips, landscape photography tips?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with specific subjects to shoot, but I can definitely recommend that you bring a tripod of some sort.  If you're hiking, I've had good luck w/ a Trekpod - this isn't as stable as a full-sized tripod, but it's great to have a device that does double-duty as a hiking stick, and it's invaluable when shooting landscapes.

I brought my Trekpod on a 10-day canoe trip earlier this summer, and not only did it help immensely with pictures, it also saved my butt a few times on portages when I was using it as a hiking stick.